# How to determine if a point is above or below a limit?

Tags: vb.net, graph, geometry

I have a program written in vb.net that creates a graph and draws various lines on it parsed from an XML file. Each line defines if points on the graph must be above or below it.

Simply put, I am looking for a way to find the closest number ABOVE and BELOW a certain point.

So say we have a straight line `{(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)}`
and a point we want to validate `(1.5,4)` Say this point needs to be ABOVE the line.

Also, i should mention that the line may not always be a straight line but have many segments representing a curve.

I suspect the easiest way to do this is to find the 2 points on the line surrounding our point on the x axis, get the slope between them and then interpolate.

So I tried this:

```
pointBelow = validationLine.points.Aggregate(Function(x, y) If(Math.Abs(x.X - paramPoint.XValue) < Math.Abs(y.X - paramPoint.YValues(0)), x, y))

pointAbove = validationLine.points.Aggregate(Function(x, y) If(Math.Abs(x.X - paramPoint.XValue) < Math.Abs(y.X - paramPoint.YValues(0)), x, y))
```

As you can see, these will obviously both return the same value, so I would like to know how I can search for the closest number in a list BELOW a given value, then do the same thing but search ABOVE that value.

P.S. it is also possible that the point we are validating may be at the exact same place on the x axis as one of the vertices on our line and I am looking for a solution that will solve this regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it's too long to comment.

It depends on the line that you are comparing it to... if your line is a function, it means it will never 'go backwards', and you just have to compare the Y-values of the point and your line at point X.

If it's not a function, then it's harder, and maybe you should ask that question on a math Q&A site, like https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/